# Having trouble with beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am very new to python and have trouble with the code below. I am trying to get either the temperature or the date on the website, but can't seem to get an output. I have tried many variations, but still can't seem to get it right..

Thank you for your help!

```
#Code below: 
import requests,bs4
r = requests.get('http://www.hko.gov.hk/contente.htm')
print r.raise_for_status()
hkweather = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
print hkweather.select('div left_content fnd_day fnd_date')
```

Comment: Try using `.` as your css delimiter instead of a space. It also looks like they changed their ids and classes

Comment: Using "." doesn't seem to work either. 

There's quite a few (maybe 10) of the 'fnd_date's, i don't mind having all of them as a list, or just the first 1. 

Tried to do a 'for'...but..didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your css selector is incorrect, you should use `.` between the tag and css classes, the tags you want are in the divs with the  `fnd_day` class inside the div with the id *fnd_content*

```
divs = soup.select("#fnd_content div.fnd_day")
```

But that still won't get the data as it is dynamically generated through an ajax request, you can get all the data in *json* format using the code below:

```
u = "http://www.hko.gov.hk/wxinfo/json/one_json.xml?_=1468955579991"

data = requests.get(u).json()

from pprint import pprint as pp
pp(data)
```

That returns pretty much all the dynamic content including the dates and temps etc..

If you access the key *F9D*, you can see the general weather description all the temps and  dates:

```
from pprint import pprint as pp

pp(data['F9D'])
```

Output:

```
{'BulletinDate': '20160720',
 'BulletinTime': '0315',
 'GeneralSituation': 'A southwesterly airstream will bring showers to the '
                     'coast of Guangdong today. Under the dominance of an '
                     'upper-air anticyclone, it will be generally fine and '
                     'very hot over southern China in the latter part of this '
                     'week and early next week.',
 'NPTemp': '25',
 'WeatherForecast': [{'ForecastDate': '20160720',
                      'ForecastIcon': 'pic53.png',
                      'ForecastMaxrh': '95',
                      'ForecastMaxtemp': '32',
                      'ForecastMinrh': '70',
                      'ForecastMintemp': '26',
                      'ForecastWeather': 'Sunny periods and a few showers. '
                                         'Isolated squally thunderstorms at '
                                         'first.',
                      'ForecastWind': 'South to southwest force 4.',
                      'IconDesc': 'Sunny Periods with A Few Showers',
                      'WeekDay': '3'},
                     {'ForecastDate': '20160721',
                      'ForecastIcon': 'pic90.png',
                      'ForecastMaxrh': '90',
                      'ForecastMaxtemp': '33',
                      'ForecastMinrh': '65',
                      'ForecastMintemp': '28',
                      'ForecastWeather': 'Mainly fine and very hot apart from '
                                         'isolated showers in the morning.',
                      'ForecastWind': 'South to southwest force 3 to 4.',
                      'IconDesc': 'Hot',
                      'WeekDay': '4'},
                     {'ForecastDate': '20160722',
                      'ForecastIcon': 'pic90.png',
                      'ForecastMaxrh': '90',
                      'ForecastMaxtemp': '33',
                      'ForecastMinrh': '65',
                      'ForecastMintemp': '28',
                      'ForecastWeather': 'Mainly fine and very hot apart from '
                                         'isolated showers in the morning.',
                      'ForecastWind': 'Southwest force 3.',
                      'IconDesc': 'Hot',
                      'WeekDay': '5'},
                     {'ForecastDate': '20160723',
                      'ForecastIcon': 'pic90.png',
                      'ForecastMaxrh': '90',
                      'ForecastMaxtemp': '34',
                      'ForecastMinrh': '65',
                      'ForecastMintemp': '29',
                      'ForecastWeather': 'Fine and very hot.',
                      'ForecastWind': 'Southwest force 3.',
                      'IconDesc': 'Hot',
                      'WeekDay': '6'},
                     {'ForecastDate': '20160724',
                      'ForecastIcon': 'pic90.png',
                      'ForecastMaxrh': '90',
                      'ForecastMaxtemp': '34',
                      'ForecastMinrh': '65',
                      'ForecastMintemp': '29',
                      'ForecastWeather': 'Fine and very hot.',
                      'ForecastWind': 'Southwest force 3.',
                      'IconDesc': 'Hot',
                      'WeekDay': '0'},
                     {'ForecastDate': '20160725',
                      'ForecastIcon': 'pic90.png',
                      'ForecastMaxrh': '90',
                      'ForecastMaxtemp': '33',
                      'ForecastMinrh': '65',
                      'ForecastMintemp': '29',
                      'ForecastWeather': 'Mainly fine and very hot apart from '
                                         'isolated showers in the morning.',
                      'ForecastWind': 'South to southwest force 3.',
                      'IconDesc': 'Hot',
                      'WeekDay': '1'},
                     {'ForecastDate': '20160726',
                      'ForecastIcon': 'pic90.png',
                      'ForecastMaxrh': '90',
                      'ForecastMaxtemp': '33',
                      'ForecastMinrh': '65',
                      'ForecastMintemp': '29',
                      'ForecastWeather': 'Mainly fine and very hot apart from '
                                         'isolated showers in the morning.',
                      'ForecastWind': 'South to southwest force 3.',
                      'IconDesc': 'Hot',
                      'WeekDay': '2'},
                     {'ForecastDate': '20160727',
                      'ForecastIcon': 'pic90.png',
                      'ForecastMaxrh': '90',
                      'ForecastMaxtemp': '33',
                      'ForecastMinrh': '65',
                      'ForecastMintemp': '28',
                      'ForecastWeather': 'Mainly fine and very hot apart from '
                                         'isolated showers in the morning.',
                      'ForecastWind': 'Southwest force 3 to 4.',
                      'IconDesc': 'Hot',
                      'WeekDay': '3'},
                     {'ForecastDate': '20160728',
                      'ForecastIcon': 'pic90.png',
                      'ForecastMaxrh': '90',
                      'ForecastMaxtemp': '33',
                      'ForecastMinrh': '65',
                      'ForecastMintemp': '28',
                      'ForecastWeather': 'Mainly fine and very hot apart from '
                                         'isolated showers in the morning.',
                      'ForecastWind': 'Southwest force 3 to 4.',
                      'IconDesc': 'Hot',
                      'WeekDay': '4'}]}
```

The only query string parameter is the [epoch timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which you can generate using the time lib:

```
from time import time
u = "http://www.hko.gov.hk/wxinfo/json/one_json.xml?_={}".format(int(time()))

data = requests.get(u).json()
```

Not passing the timestamp also returns the same data so I will leave you to investigate the significance.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the dates:

```
>>> import requests,bs4
>>> r = requests.get('http://www.hko.gov.hk/contente.htm')
>>> hkweather = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.text)
>>> print hkweather.select('div[class="fnd_date"]')
# [<div class="fnd_date"></div>, <div class="fnd_date"></div>, <div class="fnd_date"></div>, <div class="fnd_date"></div>, <div class="fnd_date"></div>, <div class="fnd_date"></div>, <div class="fnd_date"></div>, <div class="fnd_date"></div>, <div class="fnd_date"></div>]
```

But the text is missing. This doesn't seem like a problem with BeautifulSoup because I looked through `r.text` myself and all I see is `<div class="fnd_date"></div>` instead of anything like `<div class="fnd_date">July 20</div>`.

You can check that the text isn't there using regex (although using regex with HTML is frowned upon):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'<[^<>]*fnd_date[^<>]*>[^>]*>', r.text)
# [u'<div id="fnd_date" class="date"></div>', ... repeated 10 times]
```